# „Sie traf ein großer Schock!“ Warum nicht „Sie traf einen großen Schock“?

Tags: verb, accusative

Ich habe eine grammatische Frage wegen des Verbs *treffen*.

Hier habe ich einen Satz:

> Als sie dann den Ort ihrer Hochzeitsfeier sahen, traf sie *ein großer Schock*!

*Treffen* nimmt immer Akkusativ, daher dachte ich, *einen großen Schock* wäre richtig. Aber *ein großer Schock* ist die richtige Antwort. Warum?

Wenn jemand es gut erklären könnte, würde ich mich sehr freuen. Vielen Dank im Voraus!

Answer (score 14):

*treffen* verlangt den Akkusativ, das ist richtig. Hier ist allerdings *der Schock* das Subjekt im Nominativ und *sie* ist das Akkusativobjekt. Die Satzstellung weicht hier von der Wortstellung Subjekt-Prädikat-Objekt ab, die du möglicherweise erwartet hast.

Dass hier *der Schock* das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes sein muss, lässt sich (zufälligerweise) auch daran erkennen, dass das Prädikat (*traf*) im Singular steht, *sie* aber Plural ist, was sich aus dem Prädikat des Nebensatzes (*sahen*) ergibt. Schwerer zu bemerken (aber dennoch korrekt) wäre

> Als sie den Ort der Hochzeitsfeier sah, traf sie der Schock.

Comment: Zudem ist *jmd**n.** trifft der Schock* ist eine feste Redewendung, *jmd. trifft den Schock* dagegen quasi nicht existent. Weil diese Wortreihenfolge Teil der Redewendung ist, würde ich der Bezeichnung *Inversion* entschieden widersprechen: Es gibt keine feste Satzstellung im Deutschen (Deutsch ist keine SVO-Sprache), und im Falle von *jmdn. trifft der Schock* wäre die Inversion gerade das vermeintlich 'normale' Schema SVO, nämlich _?Der Schock trifft jmdn._

Comment: @CarstenS amadausamadeus2, Danke für den Hinweis, habe meinen Beitrag entsprechend überarbeitet.

Answer (score 2):

Variante 1: Schock im Akkusativ

> Die Hochzeitsgäste trafen einen großen Schock.

Das bedeutet: Die Hochzeitsgäste gingen irgendwo umher und also sie so herumgingen, stießen sie in einer dunklen Ecke auf einen großen Schock, der unentdeckt geblieben wäre, wenn die Gäste nicht herumgegangen wären.

Etwas seriöser:
Wenn die Hochzeitsgäste das Subjekt im Nominativ sind, sind sie es, welche die beschriebene Handlung aktiv ausführen, und der Schock ist das passive Objekt, an dem sich die Tätigkeit der Hochzeitsgäste manifestiert.

---

Variante 2: Schock im Nominativ

> Die Hochzeitsgäste traf ein großer Schock.

Jetzt ist der Schock das Subjekt im Nominativ, das heißt, dass der Schock aktiv etwas tut: Er trifft die Hochzeitsgäste. Die Hochzeitsgäste sind jene, die die Handlung passiv erdulden müssen: Sie werden getroffen.

Hier stehen die Hochzeitsgäste im Akkusativ. Das sieht man ihnen auf den ersten Blick nicht an, weil Artikel und Endung in beiden grammatischen Fällen gleich sind.

Entscheidend ist hier das Verb: Es stimmt immer mit dem Substantiv in Zahl und Person mit dem Subjekt überein. Sowohl die Hochzeitsgäste als auch der Schock stehen in der dritten Person, aber der Schock steht in der Einzahl und die Gäste sind in der Mehrzahl vorhanden. Das Verb steht aber auch in der Einzahl. Daher kann nur etwas das Subjekt sein, das selbst auch in der Einzahl steht, und das ist der große Schock.

In weiterer Folge muss der Teil *»die Hochzeitsgäste«* das Akkusativobjekt sein.

---

Schwieriger wäre es in diesem Beispiel:

> Als sie dann den Ort ihrer Hochzeitsfeier **sah,** traf sie ein großer Schock!

Hier beziehen sich die beiden Instanzen des Wortes *sie* auf eine einzelne weibliche Person. Das bedeutet, dass wir dann diese Varianten hätten:

> Die Frau traf einen großen Schock.
> Die Frau traf ein großer Schock.

Hier hilft das Verb nicht weiter. Beide Versionen sind grammatisch korrekt und in beiden wird das Verb in derselben Form verwendet. An dieser Stelle kommt die Semantik zum Einsatz: Welche der beiden Bedeutungen erscheint sinnvoller als die andere?

Comment: Dass beide Sätze korrekt sind und es auf die Semantik ankommt zeigt sich noch deutlicher, wenn man "Schock" durch "Pfeil" oder "Felsen" austauscht.

Answer (score 0):

... traf sie ein großer Schock

... traf sie eine Kugel

... traf sie einen alten Freund

... traf sie eine wichtige Entscheidung

Akkusativ wird verwendet für das Ziel. In den ersten zwei Sätzen ist sie das Ziel, in den letzten zwei Fällen sind “der Freund” und “die Entscheidung” das Ziel mit Akkusativ.